# Why does argument matching in C++ ignore array sizes?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, size

In this example, getSize() returns the size of an array.

```
template <class T, size_t N>
size_t getSize(T(&array)[N])
{
   return N;
}
```

While this code does not compile:

```
template <class T, size_t N>
size_t getSize(const T array[N])
{
   return N;
}
```

After some research I concluded that this means that C++ will allow something like this:

```
void func(char c[10]) {}

int main()
{
   char c[5];
   func(c);
}
```

The fact that this code compiles without even generating a warning was a surprise to me. If array size checking was implemented, it would make the code safer, and the second template would also compile and work fine.
What are the reasons behind such compiler behavior?

Comment: Because C++ inherited C's language design errors, and retained them for backward compatibility.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley. What's the problem in compiler reporting that a C-program attempts to pass a [5] array as a [10] array? This won't break any compatibility, instead it fill help find a potential error in some old code.

Comment: A parameter of an array type is not actually an array type. It is a pointer.

Comment: @bkxp That is true, I agree. But from the compiler's point of view, function parameter `char c[10]` is exactly equivalent to `char* c`, and is there merely for documentation purposes. The function expects a pointer, that's all. One should avoid this "idiom".

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley. If it was so, then the first template would not work, too. But it returns the size of the array just fine.

Comment: That is not a parameter of an array type. It is a reference to an array.

Comment: @bkxp The first example passes a reference to an array. That is a C++ thing. There's no equivalent in C, so it was possible to add that syntax because it would not break any C code.

Comment: @juanchopanza: But the fact that the first template works means that the array argument is more than just a pointer, at least at compile time.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley: So the reference to an array can hold array size, while the array type can't? Where does the reference get its size info from?

Comment: @bkxp As I said, this is C++ syntax for passing an reference to an array. Basically: A) arrays *can* decay to pointers. B) arrays cannot be passed by value. C) Function parameter `T t[N]` is the same as `T* t` (so you can pass an array and let it decay to a pointer). D) Arrays can be passed by reference, with the signature of the first example. It is confusing, I know.

Comment: An array type *can* and *does* hold a size, known to the compiler. But there are no function parameters of array types. Parameters that *look* like array types are not.

Comment: Consider using C++11 `std::array`

Answer (score 3):

Like many other things in C++, "because C does it that way".
(And many things in C are the way they are because B or BCPL did it that way.)

In C++ as in C

```
void foo(int p[10]);
```

is equivalent to

```
void foo(int p[]);
```

which is equivalent to

```
void foo(int *p);
```

That is, the parameter *looks like* an array, but is actually a pointer.
An array argument to this function is implicitly converted into a pointer to its first element.

Both C and C++ allow you to pass a *pointer* to an array of a specific size, like this

```
void foo(int (*p)[10]);

// ...
int a[10];
int b[20];
int *c;
foo(&a); // OK
foo(&b); // Not OK
foo(c);  // Not OK
```

and C++'s reference to an array of a specific size, which your template uses, follows from that.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! With so many 'deprecated' warnings a typical C++ compiler issues for potentially unsafe things, I expected it to at least warn of the array size mismatch in the argument.

Comment: To add another drop to this sea of confusion, there are actually differences between C and C++ in `void foo(T t[42]);` for user defined `T`. Although the signature are the same, it turns out C requires a complete type!

Comment: @juanchopanza That is strange. Is that a modern addition to C?

Comment: Apparently not. I have tested it with gcc and clang in `std=c89` mode. I was very surprised to discover that.